# Django Impossible arguments to GFK.get_content_type

Tags: python, django

Take the following test:

**Shell:**

```
from app.models import Campaign
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

user =  get_user_model().objects.get(pk=1)

link_db = Link()
link_db.link = "test"
link_db.save()

Campaign(status="Pending", domain="www.test.org", user=user, link=link_db).save()
```

I get the error **Exception: Impossible arguments to GFK.get_content_type!**

Why? I don't see anything wrong here and don't know what this means.

**Campaign:**

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=MESSAGE_STATUSES, default="Pending",)
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),  related_name='campaign', null=True,


    link = models.ForeignKey(Link,  related_name='campaign', null=True)
```

**Link:**

```
class Link(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()
    hits = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Link (Hits %s): %s>"%(self.hits, self.link)

    def get_short_id(self):
        _id = self.id
        digits = []
        while _id > 0:
            rem = _id % 62
            digits.append(rem)
            _id /= 62
        digits.reverse()
        return index_to_char(digits)

    @staticmethod
    def decode_id(string):
        i = 0
        for c in string:
            i = i * 64 + _char_map.index(c)
        return i
```

**Full Stack:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 327, in __init__
    signals.pre_init.send(sender=self.__class__, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 170, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/generic.py", line 50, in instance_pre_init
    kwargs[self.ct_field] = self.get_content_type(obj=value)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/generic.py", line 63, in get_content_type
    raise Exception("Impossible arguments to GFK.get_content_type!")
Exception: Impossible arguments to GFK.get_content_type!
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: That error (from contrib/contenttypes/generic.py) is inside an `else` block with the comment "This should never happen. I love comments like this, don't you?"

Comment: @Daniel Roseman GenericForeignKey you say, ok I'll post my full code as this started to happen when I added link I assumed it would be that give me a second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `get_user_model` in model definitions, as they can be evaluated before all the models are set up. Instead, you should reference `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` directly, as described [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model).

Answer (score 0):

I just got through an issue with the same error message. Was migrating a codebase from django 1.8 to 1.6 using `GenericForeignKey` field and was passing the actual object to the `create` function and expected the Generic class to find the `content_type` and `object_id` by itself from the `content_object` but I found out it didn´t. It works just fine in 1.8 but in 1.6 it seems like you have to extract the `content_type` and `object_id` yourself and passing them into the `create` function.

For the model:

```
class SomeObject(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True, blank=True, )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

So in 1.6

```
content_object = SomeOtherObject.create(first_name='Foo', last_name='bar')
SomeObject.objects.create(
    content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(content_object),
    object_id=content_object.pk
)
```

And in 1.8

```
content_object = SomeOtherObject.create(first_name='Foo', last_name='bar')
SomeObject.objects.create(
    content_object=content_object
)
```

I tried to resolve this in `pre_save` and `pre_init` methods but this occurs before those are called.
Hope it helps someone!